# "Grew big" vs "has grown big"

Tags: tense

These two tenses confuse me a lot. I happened to see my friend's sister's picture. The last time I saw her she was a little. But I was so happy to see her latest picture. My question is what am I supposd to say as "wow she grew so big" or "wow she has grown so big" and please tell me how to differentiate between the two tenses. They confuse me very much

Answer (score 2):

Tense is only part of the difference.   It may be easier to understand these verb forms if we consider tense and aspect separately.

I use the word *tense* to refer to placement in time -- past, present, or future.   "She grew" is a past tense construction.   "She has grown" is a present tense construction.

I use the word *aspect* to refer to, well, something like relationship to time.   English grammar has a continuous aspect, a perfect aspect, and a catch-all indefinite aspect.   "She grew" is an indefinite aspect construction.   "She has grown" is a perfect aspect construction.

It is customary (at least in Germanic languages like English) to talk about tense and aspect as one lumped-together thing.   We call "She grew" a *past indefinite* construction, or a *simple past* construction.   We call "She has grown" a *present perfect* construction.

Given your context, either of these forms makes sense.   You're looking at a current picture, so it shows the girl in her present condition.   The present perfect construction expresses the current condition.   You're also inferring a past action from the difference between the size you remember and the size you see in the picture.  The past indefinite construction expresses the inferred past action.

Speakers of American English are more likely to say "She grew so big."   We tend to avoid the perfect aspect when the past indefinite makes sense.   Speakers of British English use the perfect aspect more often, making "She's grown so big" more common in those dialects.

The simple past does nothing more than place the action in the past.   The present perfect places the relevance or the results of the action in the present.

Comment: I'm an American English speaker (raised in the Midwest) and shown a picture of a kid who's gotten bigger (older) than the last time I've seen the kid, I'd say "Wow, she's grown so big" over "she grew so big." Or even more likely, I'd say "she's grown so much!" Adding "since the last time I saw her" makes "she grew so big" a little better to my ears, but not much.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of continuation of the condition.

*She has grown so big* would imply that she is still as big as she was in the picture or that she is still growing. It refers to the present state.

*She grew so big* would imply that she is no longer that big.  This could be a picture of a child who went on to grow bigger still. It refers to a state in the past.

Answer (score 0):

"Has" and "had" are completed actions.

English: he has grown big.
Spanish: él ha crecido grande.
Chinese: Tā dàle

I've heard Russian and Greek have this too. I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of languages have this and native speakers don't realize it.